# How to configure AMD on Elastix?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, elastix

I need to make Elastix/Asterisk prevent calling on fax machines.

I've already asked
[How can we handle outgoing fax calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570123/how-can-we-handle-outgoing-fax-calls?noredirect=1#comment64556145_38570123) and got the main idea, but I don't know the SIP thing well and haven't found a clear step-by-step answer or code with comments, what makes it very hard to understand.

What I understand is that I need to:

1. create custom dialplan for Elastix
2. route calls to that custom dialplan if AMD is triggered

I got the .conf files including the "amd.conf" one.

How exactly should I modify those files(and which ones) to prevent calling on fax machines(if the answer machine is fax -> hang up)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need add at settings page option like M(amd) for dialout via trunk

After that you have create macro-amd context which do detect, in extensions_custom.conf